# A random walk with cyclic groups

Tags: random-walk, cyclic-groups, visualization

I conducted experiments on the following random walk:

(i) You start with $n=1$ and $k=0$.

(ii) For each $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ :

- you walk $\omega$ steps where $\omega$ is the order of $k$ in the additive group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$,
- you turn $90^\circ$ to the left.

(iii) When you have done all $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, you increase $n$ by $1$.

It gives the following drawings, respectively until $n=4$, $n=10$, $n=30$ and $n=60$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> (0) Can you help me visualise this walk better? And for $n$ greater thatn $60$? (I didn't succeed in finishing the computation.)
>
> (1) Can we prove that we will walk as far off $0$ as we want?
>
> (2) Will we cover all $\mathbb Z^2$?
>
> (3) Will we go back to $0$ infinitely many times?